# Can I trigger a backbone event for .ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want to trigger a backbone event when the view has rendered. Ideally, I'd write something like this:

```
var DetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'detailpage',
    events: {
        'ready document': '_bringSlideDown',
        'click .close-slideDown': '_closeSlideDown'
    },
```

and I would be able to create and call a `_bringSlideDown` function once the view has finished loading. This doesn't work - is there a better way to call this event?

Specifically, I want the event to only run once, which is why I'm not nesting it in the render function. I want the view to be able to render multiple times, but want to use Backbone's `.off()` method to handle this event once before unbinding it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have three points that I want to mention.

1. First, by best practice I execute Backbone code until the DOM is
   ready, so if you follow this rule, your backbone view will be
   executed after the DOM was ready(so there is no way to listen for the ready event).
2. If you want to listen for DOM additions with jQuery, you should use
   plugins like: https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery
3. Regarding your use case, instead of listen to the DOM, check in the render 
   method if is the first time that you are rendering the view using
   a flag.

I would do something like this:

```
var YourView = Backbone.View.extend({

  _rendered : false,

  events : {
    'click .close-slideDown': '_closeSlideDown'
  },

  render: function(){
    //some render stuff
    if( !this._rendered ){
      this._rendered = true;
      this._bringSlideDown();
    } 
  }

});
```

Basically